# MongoDB nested group by query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I want to count correct, incorrect and unattempted question count. I am getting zero values.

Query -

```
db.studentreports.aggregate([
{ $match: { 'groupId': 314 } },
{ $unwind: '$questions' },
{ $group: 
    {
      _id: {
       dateTimeStamp: '$dateTimeStamp',
       customerId: '$customerId'
      },
      questions : { $push: '$questions' },
      unttempted : { $sum : { $eq: ['$questions.status',0]}},
      correct : { $sum : { $eq: ['$questions.status',1]}}, 
      incorrect : { $sum : { $eq: ['$questions.status',2]}}, 
      Total: { $sum: 1 }      
    }
}
])
```

Schema structure -

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59fb46ed560e1a2fd5b6fbf4"),    
    "customerId" : 2863318,
    "groupId" : 309,  
    "questions" : [ 
        {
            "questionId" : 567,
            "status" : 0,            
            "_id" : ObjectId("59fb46ee560e1a2fd5b700a4"),           
        }, 
        {
            "questionId" : 711,
            "status" : 0,           
            "_id" : ObjectId("59fb46ee560e1a2fd5b700a3")           
        }, 
....
```

values unttempted, correct and incorrect are getting wrong -

"unttempted" : 0,
 "correct" : 0,
 "incorrect" : 0,
 "Total" : 7558.0

Group by is required based on datetime and customerId.
Can some one correct query ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You want to sum these fields only if a certain condition is met.
You just have to rewrite your group statement like this:

```
{ $group: 
    {
      _id: {
       dateTimeStamp: '$dateTimeStamp',
       customerId: '$customerId'
      },
      questions : { $push: '$questions' },
      unttempted : { $sum : {$cond:[{ $eq: ['$questions.status',0]}, 1, 0]}},
      correct : { $sum : {$cond:[{ $eq: ['$questions.status',1]}, 1, 0]}}, 
      incorrect : { $sum : {$cond:[{ $eq: ['$questions.status',2]}, 1, 0]}},
      Total: { $sum: 1 }      
    }
}
```

Check out the documentation [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/). `$eq` compares and returns true or false. So then your `$sum` cannot do anything with that result